# Валидация загружаемого файла Spring BOOT. Пропускать только image

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, multipartfile

Мне интересно как во всяких соц сетях реализована функция загрузки изображения.

пользователю говориться загрузить фоточку а вот грузить ворд то ему не разрешают.

я на spring boot разрабатываю сейчас api где нужно прописать контроллер для загрузки файлов (только изображения).

```
@PostMapping("/uploadMultipleFiles")
    public List<UploadFileResponse> uploadMultipleFiles(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files) {
//всякая логика, сохранение. сжатие. кодировка в 64base
}
```

вот как можно сделать так чтобы если загружаемые файлы изображения - контроллер их пропускал а если нет то кидал исключение?

мне приходит на ум только установить список нужных разрешений типа .jpg .png и т.п. и валидировать их регулярными выражениями. но мне не вериться что нет более простого решения.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169713/how-to-check-a-uploaded-file-whether-it-is-a-image-or-other-file?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Большинство форматов имеют несколько особых, не меняющихся байт в начале. По ним можно довольно точно можно выяснить, что за содержимое внутри файла. Для JPEG, например, первые два байта это [FF D8].

Comment: отлично, возможно если бибилиотека от Apache не справиться воспользуюсь вашим советом.